# Can a company have friends like humans do?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Stratton Oakmont founder Jordan Belfort welcomes Agent Denham
onto his yacht, Naomi:

> Jordan Belfort: Let me introduce you. This is Nicole, Heidi. Come on.
> Don't be shy. What are you guys all shy for? Don't be scared.
>
> Jordan Belfort (Says to Agent Denham): These are **friends of
> Stratton**.

Can a company have friends like humans do?

Comment: "friends" also avers that they are not paid "companions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly any word can be used in extended and figurative ways.  A friend is one who supports you, someone who is kind to you, someone who thinks well of you.  So a friend of a company is a person who supports and thinks well of the company.

It is a natural extension of the main meaning of friend. I suspect all natural languages allow for extended or figurative senses of words.

I might note there are some specific uses of "friend", such as "friend of the court" (a person who is not a part of litigation, but advises the court on some matter of law)

Comment: Also, heritage organisations like cathedrals and museums often have "Friends of X" groups who raise money to help with their upkeep.